# Rounding DOWN postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is a example query, I've been trying to find a workaround for this but my knowledge for postgresql at this time is still limited. Thanks in advance.

Sample Query:

```
select round(3.041,2) as column
```

Expected Output:

```
3.03 instead of 3.04
```

Rounding **UP** works but I need it to round **DOWN** as well if the decimal value is <5.

Comment: round(3.041-0.01,2) ?

Comment: Why on earth would you expect 3.03?  That is not what "rounding down" means.

Comment: what is your end goal in doing this rounding down. We got a function called floor that returns the closest integer less than the value?

Comment: Your math is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You can round down with some simple decimal counting like

```
SELECT 
  3.04 - POWER(10, 
    (-1 *
        CAST(
          LENGTH(
            SPLIT_PART(
              CAST(3.04 AS STRING), '.', 2
            )
          ) 
    AS INT)
    )
  )
```

However, I have no idea why you would do this. Are you sure you aren't trying to use the basic ROUND function and cut off more significant figures?

Comment: Yes, I have this kind of list of data that I am trying to copy and it seems like on their 3rd column, column 1 and column 2 is divided together. It returns a decimal and if the 3rd decimal is <5 they round down the 2nd decimal else round it up. It is indeed weird.